# ofstream::write writes zeros for part of the file

Tags: c++, windows-10, stdvector, ostream, visual-c++-2017

I would like to write the contents of a vector< int> to a binary file. This current program is supposed to save the integers 0 to 99 in the file, but it only saves the first 26 integers.

```
std::vector<int> vector;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) vector.push_back(i);

std::ofstream outfile("file.bin", std::ios::binary);
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&vector[0]), sizeof(int)*vector.size());
outfile.close();

std::ifstream file("file.bin");
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
std::size_t size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
std::vector<int> vectorRead(size / sizeof(int));
file.read((char*)&vectorRead[0], size);
file.close();

for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
    if (vector.at(i) != vectorRead.at(i)) std::cout << vector.at(i) << ", " << vectorRead.at(i) << std::endl;
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
26, 0
27, 0
...
99, 0
```

How can I write the whole vector to a file?

Comment: Try opening the file in binary mode both times - does it help?

Comment: Have you tried to check `size` to make sure it's correct? Or that any of your file operations actually succeed?

Comment: @user253751 Opening in binary mode does the trick. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: `std::ios::binary` is missing when reading.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RbF3jbXNTIyPo2U0).

Comment: Check the [ASCII-table](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg) where control character 25 (Ctrl+Z) is named "END OF MEDIUM". In text mode this is considered an end-of-file marker for DOS and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user253751 and Marek R pointed out, the issue was I was not reading in binary mode.

Before:

```
std::ifstream file("file.bin");
```

Corrected:

```
std::ifstream file("file.bin", std::ios::binary);
```